# is it possible cutting compiler complaint if return type is object?

Tags: c++

```
 pseudocode :
  function takes "int c" and "list d" 
          from start to end of the list search "c" in "list d"
               when see it 
                    return index
```

Due to writing return in iteration, compiler start to complain about non void function.
How can I cut compiler complaint ?

Note : c always in list but index of it is not be known .

EDIT : If  I change like below ;

```
  pseudocode :
  function takes "string name" and "list d" 
          from start to end of the list search "c" in "list d"
               when see it 
                    return object
```

What will I do ?

Comment: @your edit: The specific return type of your function doesn't change anything. If it's non-void, then all code paths must encounter a return of the correct (or equivalent/convertible) type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting real code would really help. I'm guessing you have something like:

```
int find(int c, list d) {
  for (*iterate over list*) {
    if (item == c)
      return index;
  }
  // <- nothing here
}
```

The compiler in most cases cannot know that list will always contain `c`. So you need to add a return statement. Something like this is usual:

```
int find(int c, list d) {
  for (*iterate over list*) {
    if (item == c)
      return index;
  }
  // Never reached
  return -1; // or throw an exception
}
```

(or choose another invalid index value). Do leave a detailed comment as to why that part is never reached.
Throwing an exception could be a good idea if you already use them - it spot bugs if/when your assumption about the list always containing `c` fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Put "fake" return after loop and put a comment like:

```
// This never should happen.
   return -1;
```

Also you may consider throwing an exception if not found...
But question was about compiler complaint so you have to have a return there.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like

```
int index = -1

search in list 
  if found 
    break;

return index;
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is pointing out to you that, if "c" is not in "list d", your program results in unspecified behavior. Figure out what your function should return if "c" isn't found, and return that, and the compiler will stop complaining. If you're really absolutely certain that "c" is in the list, then it doesn't matter what you return. But if that's true, it's a code smell.

Comment: No explanation for this downvote. Some people are bad citizens.